# Unable to run command (Xcode 7.3.1, Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, osx-elcapitan

Tried checking Target Dependencies, got rid of the UITests & Tests files from there. Any other suggestions?

I get two errors like the following:

> Unable to run command 'CpResource CLS.app' - this target might include
>   its own product.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should write the output in your question and not just post an image. Also, you might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You don't give much to go on but try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448589/this-target-might-include-its-own-product

Answer (score 0):

If you got rid of all the files with the command that causes the issue (searched in project).

Try to clean the project (in XCode menu Product-> Clean) and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

You should try **quitting Xcode**, then **copy/pasting** the files from your 'bad' project into a new one. Try checking other files like frameworks, etc too.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the app. Some names can confuse Xcode. Then try rerunning the project.

If this doesn't work, try cmd + shift + k to clean your project